# CloudFunctions: Request is sending twice

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue and I need help since I'm learning.

I have a flutter app that saves on Firebase/Firestore data, when a user requests a friendship I add it on both sender and target user, changing the IDs of sendTo and sentBy.

My problem is that CloudFunctions detect well that 2 collections from different users have been changed and notify me 2x (target user). So code is fine but should only notify once/target user

I'm using FCM to send local notifications.

```
exports.sendRequestNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}/requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const docReq = snap.data()
    /*console.log(docReq)*/

    const sentBy = docReq.sentBy
    const sentTo = docReq.sentTo
    const contentRequest = docReq.code

    if(contentRequest !== null){
        // Get push token user to (receive)
        admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .where('userId', '==', sentTo)
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(userTo => {
              /*console.log(`Found request user to: ${userTo.data().userId}`)*/
              if (userTo.data().pushToken) {
                // Get info user from (sent)
                admin
                  .firestore()
                  .collection('users')
                  .where('userId', '==', sentBy)
                  .get()
                  .then(querySnapshot2 => {
                    querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
                      /*console.log(`Found request user from: ${userFrom.data().userId}`)*/
                      const payload = {
                        notification: {
                          title: `${userFrom.data().nickname}`,
                          body: contentRequest,
                          badge: '1',
                          sound: 'default'
                        }
                      }
                      // Let push to the target device
                      admin
                        .messaging()
                        .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload)
                        .then(response => {
                          /*console.log('Successfully sent request:', response)*/
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                          console.log('Error sending request:', error)
                        })
                    })
                  })
              } else {
                console.log('User request or token not found')
              }
            })
          })
        return null
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear from your code why it would send the notification twice (since you check that `userTo.data().userId !== sentBy`). But what is sure is that you are not returning a Promise that resolves when all the asynchronous operations (`get()` and `sendToDevice()`) are completed.

I would suggest you watch the official Video Series (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which explain very well this point about returning Promises for background functions (in particular the ones titled "Learn JavaScript Promises").

In particular, you will see in the videos that if you don't return a Promise, the Cloud Function may terminate before asynchronous operations are completed, potentially resulting in some inconsistent (not logical) results .

So, you should give a try with the following adapted code, which returns the promises chain:

```
exports.sendRequestNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/requests/{requestId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const db = admin.firestore();

        const docReq = snap.data();
        /*console.log(docReq)*/

        const sentBy = docReq.sentBy;
        const sentTo = docReq.sentTo;

        // Get push token user to (receive)
        return db.collection('users')
            .where('userId', '==', sentTo)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {

                //We know there is only one document (i.e. one user with this Id), so lets use the docs property
                //See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#docs

                const userTo = querySnapshot.docs[0];

                if (userTo.data().pushToken && userTo.data().userId !== sentBy) {
                    // Get info user from (sent)
                    return db.collection('users')
                        .where('userId', '==', sentBy)
                        .get();

                } else {
                    console.log('User request or token not found')
                    throw new Error('User request or token not found');

                }

            })
            .then(querySnapshot => {

                const userFrom = querySnapshot.docs[0];

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: `${userFrom.data().nickname}`,
                        body: `requestNotify`,
                        badge: '1',
                        sound: 'default'
                    }
                }

                return admin
                    .messaging()
                    .sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error:', error);
                return false;
            })

    })
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my code for a working one, I started using a code that will be only on the user that should be notified, rather than both. You code have this issue: `Error: ReferenceError: userTo is not defined at userCollection.where.get.then.then.querySnapshot`

Comment: Oh yeah, I made a mistake forgetting that Query objects are immutable and can't be modified after being created! Corrected.

Comment: Note that in your modified code you still omit to return a Promise that resolves when all the asynchronous operations are completed. However **this is really KEY** for Cloud Functions.